# Why do we expand $S(T,V)$ and not $S(T,P)$?

Tags: thermodynamics

I wanted to find a general expression for $C_P-C_V$, which involved expanding

$$\text{d}S=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T \text{d}V+ \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_V \text{d}T.$$

I understand everything about $S$ being a function of state and how its differential is exact, and how to manipulate the Maxwell relations to obtain a proper expression. However, most texts say right off the bat that $S$ can be expanded as a function of $T$ and $V$ without proper explanation. Why do we do this, instead of say expand in terms of $T$ and $P$?

Comment: In the usual development to determine the partial derivative of enthalpy H with respect to pressure P at constant temperature T, we expand entropy in terms of T and P.

Comment: @ChesterMiller is it acceptable to expand S in terms of any set of natural variables?

Comment: Yes, but some of them are more appropriate to specific situations.